# Custom key generation in RavenDB

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb, document-database

I have sets of entities all of them are derived from abstract class

```
public abstract class NamedEntity : INamedEntity
{
    #region Public Properties

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

When I persist all entities I want to use `Name` field as a key, so I override `DocumentKeyGenerator` and provide such implementation:

```
    store.Conventions.DocumentKeyGenerator = entity =>
        {
            var namedEntity = entity as NamedEntity;

            if (namedEntity != null)
            {
                return string.Format("{0}/{1}", store.Conventions.GetTypeTagName(entity.GetType()), namedEntity.Name);
            }

            return string.Format("{0}/", store.Conventions.GetTypeTagName(entity.GetType()));
        };
```

It works fine when I persist the list of entities for the first time, but if I want to persist them again I get an exception

```
PUT attempted on document 'xxxxx' using a non current etag
```

I just started using RavenDB, so I cannot understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but it's probably not with your key generation, but how you are storing them.

On first usage you probably have something like:

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity(...);
session.Store(myEntity);
...
session.SaveChanges();
```

That part is fine, but on subsequent usage, you should not be doing the same thing.  Instead, it should be more like this:

```
var myEntity = session.Load<MyEntity>("myentities/foobar");
myEntity.Something = 123;
...
session.SaveChanges();
```

Note there is no call to `.Store()` when making changes.  This is because the entity is "tracked" by the session, and all changes to it are automatically persisted when you call `.SaveChanges()`

Comment: so if I get the set of entities from external source and just want to refresh my persisted entities, should I iterate all of them, reassign their values and then SaveChanges? Also if I let RavenDB to generate unique keys for my entities my code works just fine, could I repeat such behavior generating my own keys? What are the differences?

Comment: You could indeed do that.  If you have a lot of documents to change all at once, you might want to investigate the patching API instead.  http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates

Comment: If you let raven generate unique ids, and you store a new entity, it may not throw the exception you saw, but you are really storing a new document, not updating an existing one.  There will be two when you are done.